# What factors to consider when deciding when to split a project into microservices?

Tags: php, python, swift, google-app-engine, architecture

I'm currently working on an app that I've been developing for a while. There's plenty of different features, each independent from one another and varying in their immediacy towards the client. For instance, there's a set of files for users, a separate group for merchants, generating recommendations, CRON jobs and a set of peripherals (eg. search, chat, processing/uploading data).

At the moment I've separated most of them into separate services on `Google App Engine` and determined `Standard` or `Flexible` environments based on a frequency of requests along with the customisability that comes with adjusting the hardware for `Flexible`. They use `Google SQL` and `Firebase` frequently.

After a short break, I've come back to:

1. An expensive monthly bill from Google,
2. A returning idea - that I should merge these into just two services,
   distinguished by `Standard` or `Flexible`.

I was planning on doing exactly that but decided to ask around first and hear what I'm missing. It seems juvenile to think these are the only motivators when deciding architecture.

As for further notes:

1. The codebase is mostly Swift, Python and PHP code,
2. I'm the only one managing it,
3. Costs are important as this is a self-financed project.

Edit:

I've further revisted https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments but it doesn't go into detail about how to consider where to split a project into microservices.

Thanks for your notes :)

Comment: what services of Google App Engine you are currently using? and what services are you planning to stop using?

Comment: App engine, Google SQL, Firebase. Sorry will include that in the write-up. Thanks

Comment: What is the motivation to split the project into microservices especially if you are only person on the project ?

Comment: It's the back-end services for an app. Some features will be used frequently, others not so much and there'll be a general high fluctuation with requests throughout a day which I think is fitting for flexi. The features that don't fit this criteria should be in standard - although I'm not sure if it's that consequential to load them all onto flexi?